# Creating an animation showing API calls

Tags: angularjs, html, animation, express, svg

long time lurker, first time poster here.

I need some insight here. For our final year university project, I have created a server/service that integrates fluidsurveys and d3 to create an all in one package to collect surveys and return the results in realtime.

Here's the question: For our openhouse, I want to do something interesting. I want to create a live animation that shows some sort of visualization everytime there's an API call to the server (sort of to illustrate flow of data).

Our server's made as a MEAN stack. I was hoping to make some sort of HTML5 or SVG animation that I can sent a signal to that just shows an animated arrow of sorts when the server receives an API call or something along those lines.

I have no idea where to start as I have no experience in the area.

Any insight? Thanks!

Comment: You need to ask something more focused. What precisely are you stuck on.

Comment: Lets say I create an HTML5 animation. I see tutorials and stuff online on how I can use JS to make functions that will step through the animation based on user input like clicking a button etc. 

How can instead have one that has transition events triggered via an express server?

Thanks for your response btw!